# What does this Launchpad error building my package mean?

Tags: application-development, quickly, launchpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Launchpad failed to build after “quickly submitubuntu”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156339/launchpad-failed-to-build-after-quickly-submitubuntu)

Hello I submitted my source package to ppa via command

```
quickly submitubuntu 1.1 myppa
```

This successfully submit my application to my ppa,
but buildserver always giving errors,
Here is the buildlog [link](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/109385062/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-i386.rfus_1.2_FAILEDTOBUILD.txt.gz)

Can anyone help me in that?

I also tried with localbuild with command,

```
quickly package --extras
```

It is building .deb file successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, let's troubleshoot your problem and give you a mini-tutorial along the way.

I have [**Pastebin'd** the build-log here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1076621/) to get line numbers for reference.

1. The build aborts with this error at line 613:

   ```
   /bin/sh: 1: glib-compile-schemas: not found
   make[1]: *** [override_dh_install] Error 127
   ```
2. OK, so it's missing the binary called `glib-compile-schemas`. To find out which package supplies this, we can use the `apt-file` utility (install first):

   ```
   izx@ppauvm:~$ apt-file find glib-compile-schemas
   libglib2.0-0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/glib-compile-schemas
   libglib2.0-bin: /usr/bin/glib-compile-schemas
   ```
3. This tells us that for your build architecture, i386 (32-bit), the binary `/usr/bin/glib-compile-schemas` is provided by the package `libglib2.0-bin`.
4. Searching the build log for `libglib` shows that `libglib2.0-0` is installed, but apparently `libglib2.0-bin` **is not**:

   ```
   The following packages will be upgraded:
   apt apt-transport-https libapt-pkg4.12 libgcrypt11 libglib2.0-0
   ```
5. So to hopefully solve this problem, make `libglib2.0-bin` an explicit build dependency in the `debian/control` file, and re-upload your package to Launchpad. It builds on your local system because you certainly have that package installed :)

Comment: How to add build dependencies with quickly?

Comment: @gau1991, I would start a new question about that -- it will get much more attention.

Comment: see [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/156339/launchpad-failed-to-build-after-quickly-submitubuntu) and the accepted answer for a more detailed work around for the glib fail bug.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add `libglib2.0-bin` as a build dependency as that contains the missing `glib-compile-schemas`.

Comment: But I am using quickly, I tried manual adding build-dependency but quickly replaces it. Can you show me, hot to add it with quickly?